Nodejs mysql: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit
I have this code:
const conn = mysql.createConnection(connData);

conn.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    function query(sql) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            conn.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    }

    function createResource(name, startingPrice) {
        query("SELECT * FROM resources WHERE name = '" + name + "'").then(function (result) {
            if(result.length > 0) {
                console.log("Resource already created");
                return;
            }

            query("INSERT INTO resources (name) VALUES ('" + name + "')");
            query("SELECT * FROM resources WHERE name = '" + name + "'").then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
            return;
        });

        return;
    }

    createResource("resource1", 100);

    conn.end();
});

When I try to run it it throws an error:
Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit; 
code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT', fatal: false

I think it is because of the SELECT query into the other SELECT query, in the createResource function. What is wrong and how can i fix it?

createResource is a Promise that you forget to wait for resolution. Hence you close the connection before it even starts selecting data.

You are not waiting for any asynchronous function. Even query needs an await

Does this answer your question? Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit
